# Test class fails due to Duplicate value found error

Tags: apex, unit-test

I have an object in which i have a field `OrderNumber` which is marked as unique.I have some records for that object in the organization. Say the `OrderNumber` for those records are 1,2,3,4 etc.

Now when i create test data for the same object it doesn't let me insert data with same values and throws error

> Test Class Failure : DUPLICATE_VALUE, duplicate value found.

When i create test data with some other values i can insert records. I tried inserting the records in the `Test.startTest` `Test.stopTest` but i got the same result.

Now my question is **why i can't insert the records with same unique values in test class? why it is conflicting with the organization's data?**

Note: My test class is **not** marked as `SeeAllData=true`

Comment: I have found that at times as well. Seems the data is not completely isolated from one duplicate detection. If possible append your test record order#'s with TEST or 999 or something

Comment: @Eric Due to keeping the actual logic simple this field should keep the numbers in sequence and for checking that logic i have to create data in same sequence as in the organization and beside that i am agree that we can tweak the logic but i am still looking for some sf documentation which point to this problem.

Comment: Good luck, interested to see if there is documentation. My feeling is it is a bug but no-one is willing to go through the pain of submitting a ticket as they can usually work around it. (which is much easier)