# Test data isolation and first error: DUPLICATE_VALUE, duplicate value found: <unknown> duplicates value on record with id: <unknown>: []

Tags: unit-test

I have been facing an unusual issue today when testing: some of my tests that use to pass on an empty sandbox instance they are not passing anymore after I put some data in the sandbox. The error is

```
first error: DUPLICATE_VALUE, duplicate value found: <unknown> duplicates value on record with id: <unknown>: []
```

I am really confused because:

- I know what is the unique constraint, but the error is generated even if the insert is the first statement in my test method (isn't the DB empty, at that moment?)
- If I change that field value in the test object I am inserting to a value none of my records have, the test actually succeed.

Aren't test fully isolated with respect to data in the instance? In this case my problematic object is a custom object

Comment: http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/163253/test-class-fails-due-to-duplicate-value-found-error and http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/search?q=duplicate+value+found

Answer (score 1):

I found some official documentation:

> For **some** sObjects that have fields with unique constraints, inserting
>   duplicate sObject records results in an error. For example, inserting
>   CollaborationGroup sObjects with the same names results in an error
>   because CollaborationGroup records must have unique names. This
>   happens whether or not your test is annotated with
>   IsTest(SeeAllData=true).

*Some* is not defined though

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_testing_data_access.htm

Refer to this section:

> There might be some cases where you can’t create certain types of data
>   from your test method because of specific limitations. Here are some
>   examples of such limitations.

I thought this was interesting as well (although not specific to your issue):

> If a test makes a Visualforce request, the executing test stays in
>   test context but runs in a different thread, so test data isolation is
>   no longer enforced.